# Can I get direct all signature of stored procedure from oracle using jdbc api insted of "select* from "?

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc

I am using JDBC to get matadta of stored procedures from different databases. I am trying to get procedure signatures with parameteres. I have tried to get stored procedure names by using `getProcedures()` function and parameter name with `getProcedureColumns()`.

The problem is when I am trying to get parameters from procedures/functions in Oracle Database 11g using `getProcedureColumns()` it will return information for only those procedures which have parameters. How can I get information for all procedures by using JDBC only? I don't want to use sql commands for this. Below is the code I am using for finding parameter information.

```
package jdbc.core;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Connection conn = null;
        System.out.println("Got Connection.");
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.192.6.144:1521","system","");
        java.sql.Statement st = conn.createStatement();

        java.sql.DatabaseMetaData dbMetaData = conn.getMetaData();
        ResultSet rs = dbMetaData.getProcedureColumns(null, "dbo", "%", "%");
        while (rs.next()) {

            String procedureName = rs.getString(3);
            String columnName = rs.getString(4);    
            System.out.println("procedureSchema=" + procedureSchema);
            System.out.println("procedureName=" + procedureName);
            System.out.println("columnName=" + columnName);

        }
    }
```

Comment: [`DatabaseMetaData.getprocedures`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getProcedures-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)?

Comment: Thanks but it's return only name not parameter ..

Comment: You could combine using `getProcedures` and `getProcedureParameters`. Eg first get all names, then match and populate parameters for those procedure names.

Comment: `getProcedureColumns(...)` don't return a value for parameterless procedures. So the way to go is the like @MarkRotteveel said.

Comment: If u don't mine would you be like to give me sample example of getProcedureParameters .

Comment: Thanks Mark Rotteveel It's done using ur idea...